# Why is my iframe's document width same as iframe width?

Tags: javascript, css, iframe, width

I'm creating an iframe, like this:

```html
<!doctype html><html><head></head><body>
<iframe src="file:///C:/Users/DD/Desktop/myiframe.html" width=200 height=200 scrolling="no" frameborder=0></iframe>
</body></html>
```

and inside the iframe I'm trying to find the size of the content which may be smaller than the iframe size, but I can't get the width to ever report anything less than the 200 pixel size that the iframe was created as.

```html
<!doctype html><html><head></head>
<body style="margin:0px;border:0px;padding:0px;font-size:0px;">
<img id="myimg" width=75 height=50>
<script>
var body = document.body, html = document.documentElement;
function consoleNow() {
  console.log("body.scrollWidth x Height = " +body.scrollWidth+" x "+body.scrollHeight);
  console.log("body.offsetWidth x Height = " +body.offsetWidth+" x "+body.offsetHeight);
  console.log("html.scrollWidth x Height = " +html.scrollWidth+" x "+html.scrollHeight);
  console.log("html.offsetWidth x Height = " +html.offsetWidth+" x "+html.offsetHeight);
  console.log("body.offsetWidth x Height = " +body.offsetWidth+" x "+body.offsetHeight);
  console.log("html.clientWidth x Height = " +html.clientWidth+" x "+html.clientHeight);
  console.log("-----------------");
}
consoleNow();
function increaseSize() {
  document.getElementById("myimg").style.width = "150px";
  document.getElementById("myimg").style.height = "100px";
 consoleNow();
}
setTimeout(increaseSize,2000);
</script></body></html>

Here are the console outputs with before image resize and after:
body.scrollWidth x Height = 200 x 50
body.offsetWidth x Height = 200 x 50
html.scrollWidth x Height = 200 x 200
html.offsetWidth x Height = 200 x 50
body.offsetWidth x Height = 200 x 50
html.clientWidth x Height = 200 x 200
-----------------
body.scrollWidth x Height = 200 x 100
body.offsetWidth x Height = 200 x 100
html.scrollWidth x Height = 200 x 200
html.offsetWidth x Height = 200 x 100
body.offsetWidth x Height = 200 x 100
html.clientWidth x Height = 200 x 200
-----------------
```

In that iframe I initially have the content (the image) sized to 75x50 but all of the known/recommended methods report width to be 200. After 2 seconds I change the size of the image to 150x100 and still get the wrong width. When it comes to heights, I'm getting good numbers.

I expect that the answer will be a CSS property to be applied to the body but I'm not sure what it would be.

Answer (score 0):

The CSS `width` property for the `body` is `auto` (the default) so it takes up as much space as is available. Since the `overflow` is set to `hidden`, it won't expand beyond that if child elements are wider.

The space available is the width of the frame containing the document.

If you want to measure the width of something inside the body, then measure the width of that something.

Comment: That overflow:hidden isn't a deal-breaker for me, it was one of many attempts to limit the document/body size. In a version where I don't have that image, I want to see the content size as 0x0, and with "some content", then it be the width/height of that content. In this simplified example I could measure the image, but in the real world this iframe will be loading something out of my control (it might be an image, it might not). I want to avoid parsing the DOM to see what's there and measure it/them individually, I want the document or page size to tell me the size of what it contains..

Comment: It seems like there's an inconsistency between width and height here. Both the body's CSS width and height are set to "" (defaults is therefore auto). The height behaves as expected, it's the height of the content (see my console results, starts out at 50 and increases to 100 as I make the image larger). The width on the other hand is always >= the iframe size.

Comment: There's how width and height work normally. Height, unless set to an explicit value, is determined by the content in normal flow. Width is determined by available space.

Comment: Is there a CSS property I can apply to the body to make it work in the same way height does?